# Emission strength is over 9000 but object is still black

Tags: emission

The object is a bezier curve and I am rendering it with cycles.

[image]

Comment: Try putting the material in the first slot instead of the second.

Comment: THANKS!!! This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The first material slot must not be empty. Put the material in the first slot instead of the second.